# How to bind an Array in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I try to bind an object like this in a Action

```cs
public class MonthDataViewModel
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MoneyDataItemViewModel> MoneyCosts { get; set; }  
}
public class MoneyDataItemViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Is that possible? How do i design the form?
I try a few times but the property `MoneyCosts` won't be bind , and this is the data i submited:

```
Year=2016
Moneh=8
MoneyCosts.Title=ABC
MoneyCosts.Cost=100
MoneyCosts.Title=DEF
MoneyCosts.Cost=200
```

I saw a modelbinder called `ArrayModelBinder<T>` , how do i use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `x-www-url-formencoded` content type then try to change(if possible) your post data like below:

```
Year=2016&Month=8&MoneyCosts[0].Title=ABC&MoneyCosts[0].Cost=100&MoneyCosts[1].Title=DEF&MoneyCosts[1].Cost=200
```

> How do i design the form?

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AccountName" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Year" />
    <input type="text" name="Month" />
    @for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        <input type="text" name="@("MoneyCosts["+ i + "].Title")" />
        <input type="text" name="@("MoneyCosts["+ i + "].Cost")" />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If you use `json` content type, your data should be something like this:

```
{"Year": "2016", "Month":"8", "MoneyCosts":[{"Title":,"ABC"}, ...]}
```

in the case of `json` request you should use `FromBody` in action method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ActionName([FromBody]MonthDataViewModel model)
```

Comment: Ancient thread - I know, sorry, but is there ANY way to make use of tag helpers and post json contenttype data?

Comment: @Dynde you can write your own `JsonFormTagHelper` ,to append the javascript before or after `</form>` ,